# MacBook keyboard and trackpad on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, keyboard, macbook, touchpad

I have made a bootable SSD to run Linux off and it all works, except when I connect it to my MacBook the trackpad and keyboard do not work. I have Kernel 4.15 and I see online I need to download some drivers or something but I cannot find any guide that walks me through it so I do not break anything. If anyone can help with that process that would be amazing.

https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver
I have seen this online and it says how I can do it but I’m not sure what it means it just mentions some stuff to change.

Comment: Can you please append the link to the web page you mentioned?

Comment: What is your MacBook model?

Comment: 2017 macbook non touchbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which uses kernel 4.15

You should be able to just run this as root in the terminal and be good to go

```
sudo su root
echo -e "\n# applespi\napplespi\nspi_pxa2xx_platform\nintel_lpss_pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

apt install dkms
git clone https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.git /usr/src/applespi-0.1
dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
```

Don't forget to reboot

If you are willing to use Ubuntu 19.10, it has MacBook trackpad and keyboard support built in. It includes Linux kernel version 5.3. Everything would work after a fresh install or upgrade.

You could also try updating the kernel, a quick Google search can help you do that. It isn't a great solution, but it would probably be fine.

Comment: I actually saw that yeah. Right now actually I am trying to set it up again with 19.10 and its good but it won't let me install ubuntu from the usb I'm using to boot right now which is odd. if I can't fix this ill use the code you posted above thanks. Yeah so I've tried a few times now I can't select the usb as the device with the ubuntu iso on it for 19.10 so I'm going to go back